Sidekick PowerShell - Couldn't import module
I'm trying import the Sidekick Powershell module, Sitecore says it can't open the file.
I gave full permission to the folder for

IIS-URUS
AppPool/local-cm
IUSR

However, I'm still not having any luck.
Here’s the script I’m using:
 Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    Import-Module -Name SitecoreSidekick -Force  -Verbose

Here’s the error message I’m encountering:

Any suggestions on what might be causing this or how to resolve it?

It seems the relative path for loading nested modules is not working in the manifest file. In order to resolve this issue, you can navigate to the manifest file C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreSidekick\SitecoreSidekick.psd1 and provide the complete path in below locations.
RootModule = 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreSidekick\SitecoreSidekick.psm1'

NestedModules = @(
        'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreSidekick\Invoke-StreamingWebRequest.ps1'
        'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreSidekick\Copy-SKContent.ps1'
    )

Once these changes are done, you should be able to run the above powershell snippet inside the Sitecore Powershell ISE as below.

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any queries.

This could be an issue of the incorrect path to the Sidekick Powershell module. Ensure that the PowerShell script has the correct path to the file. If the module is located in a non-standard directory, you may need to explicitly specify the path. Ensure that the Import-Module command points to the right file location if it’s not in the default module folder (C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules).
You can try specifying the full path of the module like this.
Import-Module -Name "C:\path\to\SitecoreSidekick.psd1" -Force -Verbose

You should also check that the module itself is not corrupted or incomplete.  Try reinstalling or re-downloading the module to rule out any issues with the file itself.
Hope this helps.
